# ruby: how do you tag an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, tags, cloud, aws-sdk

how do you tag an ec2 instance create with the aws ruby sdk v2 run_instances method?

I tried 'ec2.tags.create' but that was just a guess.

Update: A deep search of github found this snippet:
    `ec2.create_tags(resources: [@launched_instance_id], tags: [ { key: 'Name', value: "#{@config[:service]}-ami"}])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [run_instances() documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#run_instances-instance_method) shows:

```
resp = client.run_instances({
...
  tag_specifications: [
    {
      resource_type: "customer-gateway", # accepts customer-gateway, dhcp-options, image, instance, internet-gateway, network-acl, network-interface, reserved-instances, route-table, snapshot, spot-instances-request, subnet, security-group, volume, vpc, vpn-connection, vpn-gateway
      tags: [
        {
          key: "String",
          value: "String",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
...
```

You can also tag an instance after it has launched by using [create_tags()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#create_tags-instance_method):

```
resp = client.create_tags({
  resources: [
    "i-abcd1234", 
  ], 
  tags: [
    {
      key: "Stack", 
      value: "production", 
    }, 
  ], 
})
```